# Flag dialog confirmation button disabled when changing back and forth from mod flag

Tags: bug, flags

It seems there's a small bug in the flag dialog. Repro steps:

1. select the moderator flag
2. input some text
3. select a different flag by clicking on another radio
4. select the moderator flag again
5. the text is still in the text box, making the flag ready to be raised, but the flag confirmation button is now disabled.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Selecting the text, re-enables the button.

Comment: Updating the text in the textbox enables the button though, so it doesn't significantly affect functionality

Comment: You are right, the button is disabled once you select another option and then click back. But I switched from one tab to another, and the button is then enabled. Very strange functionality...

Comment: Also just discovered that if you click the disabled flag button, it reenables immediately, allowing you to properly click it to submit afterwards.

Comment: @zcoop98 - still a bug, though :)

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting @Oleg's comment - nobody's saying this isn't a bug. If anything the others are supporting that it is by showing just how deep the rabbit hole of strange behaviors goes.

Comment: @BoltClock - ‍♂️ but I'd like it to be here before we accidentally "you can easily work around it" or "just use the userscript"-shame the user with the bug report :) Happened a couple of times on my memory to minor bug reports.